# Can we bring the hammer down hard on [statistical-analysis-soft]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

This is a burninate request on the [statistical-analysis-soft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistical-analysis-soft) tag. This tag

- is vague. Software specific tags typically exist (eg, [r], [stata], [sas], [spss]) The more specific tags are what we want -- questions with this tag and without any specific application (software) tag are likely to invite posts that are either too broad or a tool request.
- has no wiki text.
- has a total of 17 questions, though it has existed since 2010. Of the 17 current questions, 8 have non-positive vote totals, 8 were posted prior to 2011 (random cut off point), and only 4 have votes greater than 4. Also, with only 17 posts in the last 7 years, there is good evidence that this tag has little additional value.

These reasons alone seem to make it a prime candidate for removal. Further, it is hard to imagine a scenario where this tag would be add value to a post.

As far as I can tell, all of these questions could have the tag removed without harm to the question.

**update**
The 17 questions in the tag have been cleaned up, including removal of the tag.

Comment: We need a more punny name! I vote for **Burn [statistical-analysis-soft] in Markov Chains.**

Comment: It is hard to know what the creator of the tag even had in mind. There is no tag wiki or anything like that. The tag is worthless, so it seems like a good idea to get rid of it.

Comment: total of 17 questions, why not just remove it directly? I see no reason for burnination process, let alone ban request.

Comment: I just re-read the burninate request wiki page and it mentions that tags with 0 questions will be removed within 24 hours automatically. If no one has objections in the next 12 hours or so, I'll remove the tag. Perhaps a ban request is a bit too extreme for such a sparsely populated tag.

Comment: I think you should go ahead, with the usual caveat: don't just fix tags; fix whatever else is wrong in the post. And one of those qs has only this tag, so you'll have to figure on something to replace it.

Comment: @JohnColeman The tag field lets you type "statistical-analysis-software" and then truncates down to 25 chars. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13274/

Comment: Burn [statistical-analysis-soft] with probability ~1

Comment: @Frank I think [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033345/stacked-graphs-design) needs to be closed and deleted.

Comment: @ayhan Ok, it's closed. Not sure how far we need to downvote it before delete votes can be cast.

Comment: [statistical-analysis-soft] where it shouldn't be

Comment: This one is a [tool request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487096/how-to-implement-arima-model-using-java) that should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Victory. The tag has been removed from the system.